# How to view the data on a drive that was a part of a RAID 1 array?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid

I have removed RAID 1 hard drive from my old PC.

I connected it to my new PC as a normal SATA drive (not RAID) but I am unable to view the content.

Windows keep prompting to format it, but I dont want to format it as I want to copy the data to the new PC.

Is there any way to access this drive’s data?

[image: Screenshot of the Disk Manager]

Comment: Is Linux an option?

Comment: Hardwared RAIDs modifying structure (used sectors in the beginning or/and in the end of HDD) of disks, so such disks usually wouldn't be recognized. Simple solution is to put disk back and remove it from RAID array (make as non raid member)

Comment: Is there a way to remove it from RAID array without wiping the data...

Comment: Related: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/778988/mounting-disks-from-raid-1-array-for-data-recovery) the Link is for linux, but that may still be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do :
You can connect an additional hard drive with same/larger capacity of the volume
Download macrium reflect 7 free addition
Then clone this RAW partition into the new space.
this should give you your files back.